TinyMCE strips <br/> tags after posting
I am using TinyMCE in a post form with a textarea.
Many texts are stored in a database and may contain  tags, such as:
<p>line one<br />line two</p>

When I load such a text into the textarea, the text is still complete.
But after posting the form, the  tag is gone.
In the database I can see that the original was changed to
<p>line oneline two</p>

I also tried
remove_trailing_brs: false,

but the br-tags are still stripped.

Try providing br tag as valid tag/element which will remain in the edited text when the editor saves it:
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    valid_elements : "br"
});

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@valid_elements/
